# Length of Values doesn't match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Big hello to the Stackoverflow community,

I am trying to read in a .csv file with 1370 rows and two columns: `Time` and `Speed`.

```
Time   Speed

0       1

1       4

2       7

3       8
```

I want to find the difference in `Speed` between two time steps (e.g. `Time` `2` and `1`, which is `3`) for the entire length of the data. I want to add a new column `dS` with the previously calculated difference. The data would now look like:

```
Time   Speed  dS

0       1     NaN

1       4     3

2       7     3

3       8     1
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv

df2 = pd.read_csv ('speed.csv')

dVV = []


for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    dVV.append(df2.iloc[i+1,1] -  df2.iloc[i,1])
    break

df2['dVV']=dVV
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-4ed9fde37ff9> in <module>()
     14     break
     15 
---> 16 df2['dVV']=dVV
     17 
     18 #df2.to_csv('udds_test.csv', index=False, header=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, 
value)
   2517         else:
   2518             # set column
-> 2519             self._set_item(key, value)
   2520 
   2521     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, 
value)
   2583 
   2584         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2585         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   2586         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2587 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   2758 
   2759             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2760             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   2761             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   2762                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, 
index, copy)
   3119 
   3120     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 3121         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 
'index')
   3122 
   3123     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I am guessing that the code is breaking after the last 1370th row. How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [`pd.Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df['ds'] = df['Speed'].diff()

print(df)

   Time  Speed   ds
0     0      1  NaN
1     1      4  3.0
2     2      7  3.0
3     3      8  1.0
```

The loop method you've attempted is not recommend when vectorised solutions such as `pd.Series.diff` are available.

Comment: Thank you. Also, how do I find the average of two consecutive cells? e.g. average of speed at time 2 and 3 = 7.5

Comment: I tried 
   df2['dAvg'] = df2['Speed'].mean()
But it returns the average of the entire column.

Comment: @AkshayNarkar, Sounds like a different question. In this case, you should ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['Speed_avg'] = df['Speed'].rolling(2, min_periods=2).mean()
df['ds'] = df['Speed'].diff()
```

Output:

```
   Time  Speed  Speed_avg  ds
0     0      1       NaN  NaN
1     1      4       2.5  3.0
2     2      7       5.5  3.0
3     3      8       7.5  1.0
```